# how to do when monitoring many apps use prometheus？

Tags: prometheus

there is many apps (include many copies of a app , you know ,for testing them ) should be monitored, but prometheus seems doesnot support a mechanism that separate the data into each app's part, just like namespace.

i think that each app use a new prometheus which data are mapped in different folder, or use the lable 'namespace=?' to lable each app's metric in static config.

i don't want to attach namespace limit in promQL when user use it. make user feels they are the only user to use the monitor system, avoid interference

Is there a better way?  so many thanks and sorry for my broken english.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Prometheus automatically adds `job` and `instance` labels to every collected metric:

- The `job` label is taken from the `job_name` option, which is set in [scrape_config](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#scrape_config). The `job` label is usually used for grouping metrics belonging to a particular application (which can run on multiple hosts).
- The `instance` label usually contains TCP address (e.g. `hostname:port`) of the scraped application instance. This label allows filtering and grouping metrics by application instances.

See more details about `job` and `instance` labels in [the official Prometheus docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/jobs_instances/#jobs-and-instances)

Comment: The downside of this is that if you have multiple applications with different metrics, you get a huge list of metrics for example when creating querys/panels in Grafana.